# Ajaxifying flex lists

Tags: ajax, apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml

In html, it's possible to use jquery or javascript to refresh a list of stuff every 10 seconds or so to make it appear like it's live.

Is the same thing possible with flex Lists?

I heard it's possible to create flex with other programming language. Not sure what the details were, I think they said with javascript too. But I'm working only with mxml and actionscript, so a pure actionscript/mxml solution is what I'm after.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use jQuery with ExternalInterface: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html You can send function calls from Flash (Flex) to JavaScript and similarly from JS to Fl on demand. I'd only suggest to go this way if you have a widely used existing JS layer in your application.

Otherwise I suggest you to do the refreshing in Flex. With Timer (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/Timer.html) you can schedule those calls. Also you can measure the response time and accordingly adopt the refresh time intervals.

Answer (score 0):

In Flex you can use the HTTPService instead of hooking into Javascript. See example: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/29/dynamically-loading-xml-files-using-the-httpservice-tag/

Also, it is not possible to create Flex with Javascript only. There are other RIA tools out there, but Flex/AS requires compilation.